# Query parquet file - check if square is inside of other square

Tags: python, sql

In a python project I open *.las point cloud data. Here I calculate the minY, minX, maxY, maxX values of the point cloud data (square/rectangle).

There is a huge parquet file which exist of borders of buildings, like the blue square in the image. This parquet file has tables:

> buildingMinY, buildingMinX, buildingMaxY, buildingMaxX.

What is the fastest execution way to query this file to check if a building exist in the point cloud data.

Pseudo code:
Check if buildingMinY > minY AND < maxY ??
buildingMaxY > minY AND < maxY
??

[image: BLUE is building, RED is point cloud data]

Comment: You state *polygon* in general, but your proposed attack is specific to grid-aligned rectangles.  Clarify, please?

Comment: Also, please clarify "fastest" -- do you need shortest execution time, shortest coding time, easiest maintenance, or some other metric?

Comment: Yes I will change

Answer (score 0):

[This question](/questions/22205401/check-if-square-is-contained-in-another-square) *should* be a duplicate of yours, but it's still not efficient.

All you have to do is to check that the inner sides are within the bounds of the outer.  Since you already know that for any dimension, `minD < maxD`, you can skip a lot of comparisons.  Simply make sure that the order is what your need:

```
if buildingMinX < minX and maxX < buildingMaxX and \
   buildingMinY < minY and maxY < buildingMaxY :
    # small rectangle is inside large one ... process the hit
```

If you're familiar with `numpy` or any other vectorized package, you could check the entire data frame quickly.